# GAEにアプリをデプロイしたい。

Tags: python, python3, google-app-engine, google-cloud, google-cloud-storage

Pythonで作成したアプリをGAEにデプロイしたいのですが、エラーが吐き出されてうまく行きません。
python3 + Flaskで作成したアプリをGAEのPython37 スタンダード環境にデプロイしようとしている。

**エラー内容**

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 7 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                              
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Access Not Configured. Cloud Build has not been used in project xxxxx-xxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudbuild.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxx-xxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

**cloudbuldは必要ですか？**
cloudbuildというのを使用しないといけないみたいなのですが、他の記事などではそんなの出て来ません。これは本当に必要なのでしょうか？https://qiita.com/kai_kou/items/775bcc058aaabbdff4e7

**appengine_config.pyとは**
ドキュメントに`appengine_config.py` をルート プロジェクト ディレクトリに置かないといけないと書いてあるのですがこれはpython37 スタンダード環境でも必要なのでしょうか？
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env?hl=ja

**App Engine SDK for python必要？**
Google Cloud SDKはインストールしたと思うのですが、App Engine SDK for pythonはインストールしたかどうか覚えていないのですが、確認する方法はありますか？そもそもこれはPythonで作成したアプリをGAEにデプロイする際に必要なものになりますか？

**GAEのデプロイする前に請求の有効化は必要？**

[image: GAE開始]

App Engine アプリケーションが作成されました。の下に`開始`ボタンあってそれを押してクレジットの登録を設定してからじゃないとデプロイできないのでしょうか？
作成されたとあるのでGAEの設定みたいなのは済んでる気がするのですが初めて触るのでいまいち仕組みが分かりません。

初心者で色々わからない事があり、GAEに作成したアプリをデプロイできません。
ご教授頂けるとと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

確かクレジット設定してないと出来ないですよ